# Why is the multiplicity identity taken as an axiom? (Vector Spaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

While reading a textbook on Linear and Geometric Algebra, I found a quite good exercise question:

"Axiom $5$ states that $1\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{v}$. Why do we take this as an axiom? Isn't it obvious?" (Vector Spaces)

My guess is that, since I have used that axiom to prove theorems, that means it is essential. I am not quite sure of how good of an answer that is.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to prove this axiom using the other axioms. If you can, then it should not be its own axiom. If you cannot, then it should (and perhaps it’s not so obvious ;)

Answer (score 3):

There are two main reasons we take it as an axiom:

1:  It's how we want our field and our vectors to interact
2:  It can't be proved from the other axioms.

Comment: Thanks for adding point 1. I have a more concrete answer to that now.

Answer (score 1):

You can take any structure $(V,+)$ that satisfies all the additive axioms and then define a scalar multiplication by making every product the zero vector.  This satisfies all of the axioms for a vector space except for the identity axiom.  Now see how many theorems in your textbook hold.  (Many still do.)

This axiom states a very convenient and natural property, but by the construction I gave it does not follow from the other axioms.

Comment: Why the downvote?  What is wrong?